# Tooltip on mouseover d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Within a Callbackfunction I have this:

```
/...
feature.on("mouseover",function(d) { 
    d3.select(this)
    .transition()
    .ease("cubic")
    .duration(10)
    .attr('r', function (d){ 
     return (d.x);
    })
        .tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");
      });
```

My `tooltip` is defined like so:

```
var tooltip = d3.select("body")
    .append("div")
    .style("position", "absolute")
    .style("z-index", "10")
    .style("visibility", "hidden")
    .text("a simple tooltip");
```

However, the tooltip won't pop up. Any ideas why?
How would I append the tooltip to the `mouseoverevent`? And: How would I change the text in there (assuming I want text from my data which I can access with `function(d) {....`)

Code extracted from [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/JpVkqaZ1AmFdBbOMwMup?p=preview)

Comment: use [d3tip](https://github.com/Caged/d3-tip). it will work depend on your data on your node. and it has function like show and hide that you can use on mouseover and mouseout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First give an ID or class to your tooltip for selection like this:

```
var tooltip = d3.select("body")
    .append("div")
    .attr("id", "mytooltip")
    .style("position", "absolute")
    .style("z-index", "10")
    .style("visibility", "hidden")
    .text("a simple tooltip");
```

Next Instead of doing this:

```
feature.on("mouseover",function(d) { 
    d3.select(this)
    .transition()
    .ease("cubic")
    .duration(10)
    .attr('r', function (d){ 
     return (d.x);
    })

        .tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");//this is wrong
      });
```

Do this to show tooltip on mouse over:

```
feature.on("mouseover",function(d) { 
    d3.select(this)
    .transition()
    .ease("cubic")
    .duration(10)
    .attr('r', function (d){ 
     return (d.x);
    });
    //show tooltip on hover
    d3.select("#mytooltip")
    .style("visibility", "visible")//set style to it
    .text("new tooltip")//set text to it
   });
```

Furthermore, add this for the tooltip to show up next to the mouse (as shown [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/JpVkqaZ1AmFdBbOMwMup?p=preview))! Otherwise the tooltip probably gets displayed somewhere on your site where you cannot see it!

```
feature.on("mousemove", function() { 
    return tooltip.style("top", (d3.event.pageY-10)+"px") 
    .style("left",(d3.event.pageX+10)+"px"); 
    });
```

Comment: Hm, that did not do the trick. Do i have to define `var tooltip..` within the callback?!

Comment: no i am selecting using the id of tooltip `d3.select("#mytooltip")` make sure the tooltip is made before the mouseover callback

Comment: It is, but it is outside the callback where the mouseover is in. The structure is `callback function -> do something -> mouseover function`. Would I need to `var tooltip = d3.select("body")` change that do something different? What my mouse is hovering over are circles on a map. I tried to replace `body` with `circle` but that did not do the trick

Comment: do you get any errors on the console...or best if you can make a fiddle.

Comment: Nope, there are no errors in the console. The `mouseover` still works with all the effects, but the tooltip does not show.

Comment: in mouseover when you do `console.log(d3.select("#mytooltip").size(), "the size")` what do you get on  console.

Comment: Why would I need that `d3 select`? In the example I posted the variable `tooltip` is accessed with `.tooltip`?!